# JavaScript and extending 3rd party API

Tags: javascript

I'm updating my knowledge about JavaScript and I stuck on one lesson task.
I have API that is returning string...

```
API.workerName = function (worker) {
   return worker.firstName + ' ' + worker.lastName;
};
```

The task is to prefix returning string and not change API, but extend it. I also have to avoid copying & pasting code, because 3rd party code can change. I should re-use it instead.
What I did is change this function after loading API...

```
API.workerName = function (worker) {
   return '(' + worker.position + ') ' + worker.firstName + ' ' + worker.lastName;
};
```

... but I think I did it wrong.

Comment: By changing `API.workerName` aren't you changing the API?

Comment: **tymeJV** - Script was working, but I struggle with fact, that I did it wrong.
**Andy** - that is why I write here, for help... and point me my wrong ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the method, you should save the old definition and call it from your extension:

```
API.oldWorkerName = API.workerName;
API.workerName = function(worker) {
    return '(' + worker.position + ')' + API.oldWorkerName(worker);
};
```

Or maybe this is what your lesson is looking for:

```
API.workerPositionAndName = function(worker) {
    return '(' + worker.position + ')' + API.workerName(worker);
};
```

Comment: I can't believe that I miss this :D It was so simple... thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Another neat way to save the old definition and also make it unavailable to anybody else, would be to do something like this using IIFE to create a closure:

```
API.workerName = (function() {
    var old = API.workerName;     // this old version is only available inside your new function
    return function(worker) {
        return '(' + worker.position + ')' + old(worker);
    }
})();
```

Here's an example:

```js
API = {
    workerName: function (worker) {
        return worker.firstName + ' ' + worker.lastName;
    }
};

API.workerName = (function () {
    var old = API.workerName;
    return function (worker) {
        return '(' + worker.position + ')' + old(worker);
    };
})();

alert(API.workerName({firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Blogs", position: "Lackey" }));
```